# AJAX load JSON data and storing it at angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I am new at AngularJS. I am realy sorry if my question is stupid, but I can't find decision for two days. So, I have a service, which must load data via `$http` to itself during initialization and store it. I found some info about `promises`, but it will load data every time when I access it. But I would like that this data was loaded once and can be changed and saved. For better understanding this is how I would like

```
app.run(function ($http, MeasurUnitsService) {
        $http.get('jsonData/tabs.json').success(function (data) {
            MeasurUnitsService.tabs = data;
        });

        $http.get('jsonData/measurmentUnits.json').success(function(data){
            MeasurUnitsService.measurmentUnits = data;                      
        });
    });


angular.module("emis-calc").service('MeasurUnitsService', function($http){  
     var tabs = {};
    var measurmentUnits = {};   
    var ConvertTo = function(){
        // some logic with accessing to measurmentUnits 
        // measurmentUnits is empty
        return result;
    }
    return {
        convertTo : ConvertTo,
        tabs : tabs,
        measurmentUnits : measurmentUnits
    }       
})
```

But as far as I understand,  because `$http.get()` is Asynchronous and closures, `MeasurUnitsService.tabs` and `MeasurUnitsService.measurmentUnits` always is `{}`at controllers and other services. I feel that it is easy to implement, but can't find it at all. Maybe there is any `lock()` method?
Also, if it isn't too difficult, could you explain more detailed and where is my main mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract your http request in a service, and use that service in your controllers.

```js
angular.module("emis-calc").service('MeasurUnitsService', function($http){  
   var tabs = null; 
  
   function getTabs(cb) {
     if(tabs) {
       cb(tabs) 
     } else {
       $http.get('jsonData/tabs.json').success(function (data) {
         tabs = data;
         cb(tabs);
       });
     }
   }
  
    return {
      getTabs
    }
```

This way your data only gets loaded once.

Comment: Of course you can use Promises instead of callbacks